# Adding new fields to the Object Change History model (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing my todo in django. I want to add not just the entry "task changed" to the "history" tab, but also two additional fields: "was" - "became". How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide some code. Your models + the views

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.